# Angular: Correct way to propagate an exception in route resolver to custom global error handler

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling

I have simple route resolver:

```
@Injectable()
export class DeviceResolver {
    constructor(private deviceService: DevicesService) {}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        const id = +route.params['id'];
        if (id === 0) {
            return {};
        }
        const promise = this.deviceService.getDevice(id).toPromise()
        .then(
          data => Promise.resolve()
        ).catch(
          error =>  {
            console.log('[DeviceResolver]', error);
            throw error;
          }
        );

        return promise;
    }
}
```

and simple global custom error handler:

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorsHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    handleError(error: any) {
        // Log the error anyway
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

If an exception occurred in the resolver, the catch handler of the promise is executed and in console is printed:

```
[DeviceResolver] HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders,...
```

This is fine. It's an object instance from HttpErrorResponse.

In the ErrorsHandler however the console output is:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},
```

Why the original exception have been caught and wrapped in another Error object?
How can I have the original exception in the global error handler?

Please note that this is happening only in a resolver. If I use direct service call from a component, the exception is thrown and propagated correctly to global error handler.